# Kafka : How to re-consume un committed / not Acknowledged message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We are using manual commit strategy. We have configured a bean that commits all Successfully consumed messages. We are trying to add a logic to re-consume not acknowledged messages. We are facing problem that same message gets consumed but the time interval for re-consumption is not uniform. Sometimes gets re-consumed quickly, but sometimes takes hours.

How can we make sure that uncommitted messages gets consumed within a specified time.

Comment: Well I am not sure why would you re-consume a message or why would you want to consume an unacknowledged message? If kafka broker is configured with ack=all or ack=leader then consumer will only consume acknowledged messages. My point is that maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a `seek()` operation on the `Consumer` to reset it to a specific offset.